# Using Lightning Out for external apps is beta right now, does it mean we cannot use it in production?

Tags: lightning

Using Lightning Out for external apps is beta right now. However considering that using Lightning Out for Visualforce page is allowed in production org therefore technically we can use lightning out for external app as well in production. Kindly let me know is there any technical limitation for not being able to use Lightning Out in production as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning out for visual force is not in beta so you are fine to use it

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm

Lightning out for any app outside salesforce is in beta and technically should not be packaged

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm

You mention VF in your question as a supporting fact so not sure which you are asking about.

Comment: Hi @Eric, the reason I mentioned VF as supporting fact is that both VF and external app has the same dependency i.e. creating a lightning out dependency app and CORS configuration in Salesforce instance. If one is GA then technically there is nothing which is stopping me using that dependency app in external application. –

Comment: Hi @Eric, If i understood correctly , i should be able to use lighting out for external app in production but should not package it because it is not GA or there is anything which Salesforce may rollback e.g. blocking CORS for lightning out for external website? In short should i not even propose to the customer just because it is in BETA release?